# How can I prevent XAML items from disappearing when their centres leave the map bounds?

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I have added XAML elements to my `MapControl` as according to the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi#add-xaml).

However when the centre of the item leaves the map bounds it no longer draws, so when zoomed in large items disappear when the centre is no longer visible.

In my case I am drawing a circle of zone of interest around a point, but when you zoom in to street level the centre often leaves the map and the circle vanishes.

How can I ensure the XAML continues to draw when it is still partially on the screen and not just the centre point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the particular problem - in my case the XAML item I was attaching was contained at the top level in a `Canvas` control which had an `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of zero. Presumably the clipping happens with the map based on the parent container so negative margins and canvas controls etc. might cause premature vanishing of content.

I refactored the XAML so the top level was a `Grid` and wholly contained the child items and the map worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do this. Attached XAML isn't designed to draw circles on the ground like this - it's meant more for attaching things like an info box to a pushpin where you need XAML input boxes or something more than just a static image.
For a circle on the ground, it's recommended to use a MapPolygon:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapPolygon
This will also work correctly in all projections and views, while attached XAML won't (if you tilt or rotate the map, change from Mercator to globe, etc the bounds of how you drew the XAML polygon will shift relative to the ground).